# TYPO3 Routing Multidomain slug is /1

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

We have a problem with the auto generated slug for rootpages in the new routing of TYPO3 9.5.4.

this is the domain setup:

- configs (not marked as rootpage, stores config files)
- domain A (flagged as rootpage, has a siteconfig, has subpages)
- domain B (flagged as rootpage, has a siteconfig, has subpages)
- domain C (flagged as rootpage, has a siteconfig, has subpages)

All domains have the slug `/` which works for a while, but after a while some slugs change to `/1` for no reason, and we're unable to change that via the backend. The only possible solution is to change the slug in the db directly.

Is anyone experiencing the same behavior, is there some configuration missing or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: You should also check if you have sys folders below this root page with no slug. Because sys folders without a slug are generating "/" for slug which could lead to "/1" for root page if root page will be edited and saved afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this seems to be a bug and is worked on as you can see here:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87884

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. the URL was /1 or /2 ... If I recreated the slug in the page properties, it was correct. However, when I used the PageSlug Wizard in the InstallTool it was /1 again.

My problem was the old realurl tables.
The wizard will check if RealUrl has already created a URL here, if so it will be taken. After emptying and removing the tables "tx_realurl_pathcache" and "tx_realurl_pathdata", I was able to generate new correct urls with the InstallTool Wizard

Comment: we´ve never had realURL installed as this is a new TYPO3 9.5 project. but your problem sounds strange too ;)

Comment: The PageSlug Wizard is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Still doesn't seem to be solved under some circumstances: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90736